# Beginner Python OLS without explicit numbers, IE. DataFrame

Tags: python, numpy, regression

I need help understanding running OLS (or any machine learning) in Python. I have installed all associated packages, ie. pandas, numpy, statsmodels, scipy, etc...

Here is my basic example:

```
df3= DataFrame({'revenue':[5,7,4,5,3,6,4,7,4,8,3,4],'cost':[2,4,4,3,6,7,5,4,7,23,4,7], 'overhead':[3,4,5,6,4,3,4,5,4,3,4,5]})
df3
df3.loc[0,'cost'] = 4
df3
df3.loc[12]=[1,5,8]
df3
```

Ok Now because I have additional rows in my DataFrame I do not want to just copy and past the independent and dependent variables in to my regression formula which is this

OLS Regression Formula

```
df3= pd.DataFrame({"cost":[#Numbers would go here], "overhead":[#Numbers would go here], "revenue": [#Numbers would go here]})
reg = ols (y=df3["cost"], x=df3[["overhead","revenue"]])
reg
print(df3.to_csv(columns=['cost'], sep='\t', index=False))
```

So I used this csv formula to get individual columns from the DataFrame so that I may just copy them into excel and then copy them back into my Regression formula to solve. But what if I wanted to just use Python and not have to copy and paste back and forth between it and other software.

Is there a way without any other software to reference inside the OLS regression formula my "cost", "overhead" and "revenue" data without having to explicitly type in each individual number?

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. It is unclear what numbers you want to use, where, for what purpose. Why are you randomly changing numbers after defining your df? Where did the `ols` function come from? Please [edit] your question and add an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), with example input, expected output, and actual output. Please also include the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks you are getting. You also need to describe much more clearly what you are doing, and what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The purpose of the exercise is to show even after you change your DataFrame with the Loc[] function you don't have to go back and retype your independent and dependent variables. Imagine a case in which we did not only add a single row to the DF but instead we added 50 new rows to the DF. Then in that case it clearly would not be time efficient to go back and have to retype all the inputs in to your OLS regression. Thank you so much for your comments!

Answer (score 0):

So to answer my own question this is what I did. 
I used the matrix function and turned my DataFrame into an Array

numpyMatrix = df3.as_matrix()

numpyMatrix

kk=np.array(numpyMatrix)

kk

Then Printed out each column of data to copy and paste into my own OLS Formula

kk[:,0]

kk[:,1]

kk[:,2]

df3= pd.DataFrame({"cost":[4,  4,  4,  3,  6,  7,  5,  4,  7, 23,  4,  7,  1], "overhead":[3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 5], "revenue": [5, 7, 4, 5, 3, 6, 4, 7, 4, 8, 3, 4, 8]})

reg = ols (y=df3["cost"], x=df3[["overhead","revenue"]])

reg

You can just copy and paste the array outputs into the OLS formula to solve. 
I don't think this is the best way to solve this by a long shot but at least I didn't need to use any other software.

Thank you again Stackoverflow users,
I hope to hear your comments

Here is the full print out. Sorry for any confusion
Thank you for your time

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
print ('Pandas Version:' + pd.__version__)
from pandas.stats.api import ols
import numpy as np
print ('numpy Version:' + np.__version__)
from numpy import array
from numpy import array
from numpy import mean
from numpy import median
from numpy import std
from numpy import var
from numpy import amin
from numpy import amax
from numpy import nanmin
from numpy import nanmax
from numpy import ptp
from numpy import percentile
from numpy import average
from numpy import nanmean
from numpy import nanstd
from numpy import nanvar
from numpy import corrcoef
from numpy import correlate
from numpy import cov
from numpy import histogram
from numpy import histogram2d
from numpy import histogramdd
from numpy import bincount
from numpy import digitize
import collections
import math
import scipy.stats
import statsmodels.api as sm
from scipy import stats
import statsmodels as sm
import pylab as pl
from numpy.random import rand
from numpy.random import randn
from numpy.random import randint
from numpy.random import random_integers
from numpy.random import random_sample
from numpy.random import random
from numpy.random import ranf
from numpy.random import sample
from numpy.random import choice
from numpy.random import bytes
from numpy.random import shuffle
from numpy.random import permutation
from numpy.random import beta
from numpy.random import binomial
from numpy.random import chisquare
from numpy.random import dirichlet
from numpy.random import exponential
from numpy.random import f
from numpy.random import gamma
from numpy.random import geometric
from numpy.random import gumbel
from numpy.random import hypergeometric
from numpy.random import laplace
from numpy.random import logistic
from numpy.random import lognormal
from numpy.random import logseries
from numpy.random import multinomial
from numpy.random import multivariate_normal
from numpy.random import negative_binomial
from numpy.random import noncentral_chisquare
from numpy.random import noncentral_f
from numpy.random import normal
from numpy.random import pareto
from numpy.random import poisson
from numpy.random import power
from numpy.random import rayleigh
from numpy.random import standard_cauchy
from numpy.random import standard_exponential
from numpy.random import standard_gamma
from numpy.random import standard_normal
from numpy.random import standard_t
from numpy.random import triangular
from numpy.random import uniform
from numpy.random import vonmises
from numpy.random import wald
from numpy.random import weibull
from numpy.random import zipf
from numpy.random import RandomState
from numpy.random import seed
from numpy.random import get_state
from numpy.random import set_state
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
from scipy import stats
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm
from numpy import array
from numpy import mean
from numpy import median
import collections
import math
from pandas.stats.api import ols




df3= DataFrame({'revenue':[5,7,4,5,3,6,4,7,4,8,3,4],'cost':[2,4,4,3,6,7,5,4,7,23,4,7], 'overhead':[3,4,5,6,4,3,4,5,4,3,4,5]})
df3
Out[62]:
cost    overhead    revenue
0   2   3   5
1   4   4   7
2   4   5   4
3   3   6   5
4   6   4   3
5   7   3   6
6   5   4   4
7   4   5   7
8   7   4   4
9   23  3   8
10  4   4   3
11  7   5   4
In [63]:

df3.loc[0,'cost'] = 4
df3
Out[63]:
cost    overhead    revenue
0   4   3   5
1   4   4   7
2   4   5   4
3   3   6   5
4   6   4   3
5   7   3   6
6   5   4   4
7   4   5   7
8   7   4   4
9   23  3   8
10  4   4   3
11  7   5   4
In [64]:

df3.loc[12]=[1,5,8]
df3
Out[64]:
cost    overhead    revenue
0   4   3   5
1   4   4   7
2   4   5   4
3   3   6   5
4   6   4   3
5   7   3   6
6   5   4   4
7   4   5   7
8   7   4   4
9   23  3   8
10  4   4   3
11  7   5   4
12  1   5   8
In [30]:

df3.iloc[:,[0]]
df3.iloc[:,[1]]
df3.iloc[:,[2]]
Out[30]:
revenue
0   5
1   7
2   4
3   5
4   3
5   6
6   4
7   7
8   4
9   8
10  3
11  4
12  8
In [72]:

​
​
​
​

In [70]:

jk=df3.iloc[:,[0]]
df3.ix[:,1]
Out[70]:
0     3
1     4
2     5
3     6
4     4
5     3
6     4
7     5
8     4
9     3
10    4
11    5
12    5
Name: overhead, dtype: int64
In [80]:

numpyMatrix = df3.as_matrix()
numpyMatrix
Out[80]:
array([[ 4,  3,  5],
       [ 4,  4,  7],
       [ 4,  5,  4],
       [ 3,  6,  5],
       [ 6,  4,  3],
       [ 7,  3,  6],
       [ 5,  4,  4],
       [ 4,  5,  7],
       [ 7,  4,  4],
       [23,  3,  8],
       [ 4,  4,  3],
       [ 7,  5,  4],
       [ 1,  5,  8]], dtype=int64)
In [75]:

print (df3.to_csv(columns=['cost'], sep='\t', index=False))
cost
4
4
4
3
6
7
5
4
7
23
4
7
1

In [94]:

kk=np.array(numpyMatrix)
kk
Out[94]:
array([[ 4,  3,  5],
       [ 4,  4,  7],
       [ 4,  5,  4],
       [ 3,  6,  5],
       [ 6,  4,  3],
       [ 7,  3,  6],
       [ 5,  4,  4],
       [ 4,  5,  7],
       [ 7,  4,  4],
       [23,  3,  8],
       [ 4,  4,  3],
       [ 7,  5,  4],
       [ 1,  5,  8]], dtype=int64)
In [100]:

kk[:,0]
Out[100]:
array([ 4,  4,  4,  3,  6,  7,  5,  4,  7, 23,  4,  7,  1], dtype=int64)
In [101]:

kk[:,1]
Out[101]:
array([3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 5], dtype=int64)
In [102]:

kk[:,2]
Out[102]:
array([5, 7, 4, 5, 3, 6, 4, 7, 4, 8, 3, 4, 8], dtype=int64)
In [103]:

df3= pd.DataFrame({"cost":[4,  4,  4,  3,  6,  7,  5,  4,  7, 23,  4,  7,  1], "overhead":[3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 5], "revenue": [5, 7, 4, 5, 3, 6, 4, 7, 4, 8, 3, 4, 8]})
reg = ols (y=df3["cost"], x=df3[["overhead","revenue"]])
reg
Out[103]:

-------------------------Summary of Regression Analysis-------------------------

Formula: Y ~ <overhead> + <revenue> + <intercept>

Number of Observations:         13
Number of Degrees of Freedom:   3

R-squared:         0.3185
Adj R-squared:     0.1822

Rmse:              4.8625

F-stat (2, 10):     2.3363, p-value:     0.1470

Degrees of Freedom: model 2, resid 10

-----------------------Summary of Estimated Coefficients------------------------
      Variable       Coef    Std Err     t-stat    p-value    CI 2.5%   CI 97.5%
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      overhead    -2.8085     1.5201      -1.85     0.0944    -5.7878     0.1709
       revenue     0.7575     0.7885       0.96     0.3594    -0.7880     2.3029
     intercept    13.9969     8.0440       1.74     0.1125    -1.7694    29.7631
---------------------------------End of Summary---------------------------------
```

Comment: You still are not showing your own attempt to solve the problem.. You need to read the Pandas library documentation...it has some decent examples that my get you going in the right direction...You for the most part only need to import Pandas not all the NP imports,,, You have not shown your output.